Uncaught runtime errors: Timeout while waiting for layer "root" to become ready
Came to a point of needing Webpack, due to needing loaders, for our application to upgrade to latest version of third-party library. Have tried to pinpoint the source of the issue, using various devtools (source map types), logging from the Overlay class, to no avail. Haven't been able to find anyone with this same issue. Any tips or help would be appreciated. Also, first time poster - apologies if missing info.
Webpack Config:
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/entry.js',

    //devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        extensionAlias: {
          '.jsx': ['.tsx', '.jsx'],
          '.js': ['.ts', '.js'],
        },
    },

    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(jsx?|tsx?)$/,
                exclude: [/photon_painter.js/],
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                  cacheDirectory: true,
                  configFile: "./transpile-browser.babelrc"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.txt$/i,
                use: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: ['img-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(manifest\.json)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
        ]
    },

    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        open: true,
        static: [{
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
          }]
    }
}


Try setting a higher aggregateTimeout under watchOptions
docs and references here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptions
Let me know if that helped

Thanks for the suggestion. Tried this and still had the error.
